# I'am Getting 'bad decrypt' error In Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
 class encryptedDataClass {
   constructor(massage){
     this.algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc'
     this.initVector = crypto.randomBytes(16);
     this.massage = massage;
     this.Securitykey = crypto.randomBytes(32);
   }

   encrypted(){
     const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(this.algorithm, this.Securitykey, this.initVector);
     let encryptedData = cipher.update(this.massage, "utf-8", "hex");
     return encryptedData += cipher.final("hex");
  }
  decrypted(){
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(this.algorithm, this.Securitykey, 
    this.initVector);
    let decryptedData = decipher.update(this.massage, "hex", "utf-8");
    return decryptedData += decipher.final("utf-8");
 }

 }
 const secureName = new 
 encryptedDataClass("850749d212e39c8e24aee37bbb43e3c1eaee69ea592eeaeb93da5c83437f64a0") 
 console.log(secureName.decrypted())
```

I created that key using `encrypted` function but I can't decode that key, I'm getting an error:

> 06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Well, you're generating new secret keys and IVs for each instance, so no instance can possibly decrypt a message created by another instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As AKX mentioned, you're creating a new IV everytime and when decrypting, you need the original IV. See my solution below. I'm storing the IV and later retrieving it by splitting the string on the "."

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const algorithm = "aes-192-cbc"; // algorithm to use
const password = 'defineaPassword';
const key = crypto.scryptSync(password, 'salt', 24); // create key
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16); // generate different ciphertext everytime

module.exports = {
    encryptAndBase64 (messagetext) {
        try {
            const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16); // generate different ciphertext everytime
            const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
            const ciphertext = cipher.update(messagetext, 'utf8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex'); // encrypted text
            return `${iv.toString('base64')}.${ciphertext}`;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(`error while encrypting:  ${e.message}`);
            return messagetext;
        }
    },
    decrypt (messagetext) {
        const split = messagetext.split('.');
        const iv = split[0];
        messagetext = split[1];
        const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, Buffer.from(iv, 'base64'));
        return decipher.update(messagetext, 'hex', 'utf8') + decipher.final('utf8'); // deciphered text
    },
};
```

Comment: In this answer, `algorithm` and `key` are undefined.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what is value of algorithm and key value ? I defined key =crypto.randomBytes(32) and algorithm = crypto.randomBytes(16) but it didn't work right now

Comment: sorry I've added the algo and key.